# Console.Write deletable characters

Tags: c#, console

Is there a way to write to `Console` a deletable char?

E.g.

```
// input request
Console.Write("Enter session number: ");

// suggestion input that could be deleted by user
Console.WriteDeletable(currentSessionId)
```

This should output something like:

```
Enter session number: 2514656
```

Then the user may want to delete the integer part and type its own session id.

```
Enter session number: 251← ← ← ←
```

Is there such thing?

NB: I don't want to delete chars programmatically (i.e. via `Write("\b")`), I want them to be deletable from console window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
    Console.Write("Enter session number:");
    SendKeys.SendWait("2514656"); //editable
    var sessionNumber = Console.ReadLine();
```

We simulate the user sending 2514656 so that the console will wait for user return input before the input is collected into the *sessionNumber* variable.

Comment: SendKeys use the Win32 APIs, on which WinForm was built.